# Qt C++ ListView use QAbstractItemModel append data inaccurate positioning

Tags: c, qt

Using a custom data model, if the current browsing position exceeds 100, after adding data, it will locate to the 100th position;

ListModel:

```
header:
#include <QAbstractListModel>

class ChatListItemModal: public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ChatListItemModal(QObject *parent = 0);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    void addChatItems(QVector<QString> items);
private:
    QVector<QString> chatItem;
};

cpp:
#include "chatlistitemmodel.h"

ChatListItemModal::ChatListItemModal(QObject *parent): QAbstractListModel(parent)
{

}
int ChatListItemModal::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return (parent.isValid() && parent.column() != 0) ? 0 : this->chatItem.size();
}
QVariant ChatListItemModal::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if (index.isValid() && index.row() < chatItem.size() && index.row() >= 0 && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
       return QVariant::fromValue<QString>(chatItem.at(index.row()));
    return QVariant();
}
void ChatListItemModal::addChatItems(QVector<QString> items)
{
    if (items.isEmpty())
        return;
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),
                    chatItem.size(),
                    chatItem.size() + items.size() - 1
                    );
    chatItem.append(items);
    endInsertRows();
}
```

QScrollView:

```
header :
#include "chatlistitemdelegate.h"
#include "chatlistitemmodel.h"

#include <QListView>
#include <QVector>

class ChatListScrollView: public QListView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ChatListScrollView(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void render();
    void onAddChat(const int count = 0);
private:
    ChatListItemModal *listModal;
    ChatListItemDelegate *listItemDelegate;
};

cpp:

#include "chatlistscrollview.h"


ChatListScrollView::ChatListScrollView(QWidget *parent): QListView(parent)
{
    render();
}
void ChatListScrollView::render()
{
    setFrameShape(QListView::NoFrame);
    setResizeMode(QListView::ResizeMode::Fixed);
    setLayoutMode(QListView::LayoutMode::Batched);
    setFlow(QListView::TopToBottom);
    setMovement(QListView::Static);
    setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents);
    setAutoScroll(true);
    setUniformItemSizes(true);
    viewport()->setAutoFillBackground(false);
    listItemDelegate = new ChatListItemDelegate(this);
    setItemDelegate(listItemDelegate);

    listModal = new ChatListItemModal(this);
    setModel(listModal);
    scrollToBottom();

}
// parent component trigger
void ChatListScrollView::onAddChat(const int count)
{
    int dataCount = listModal->rowCount();
    QVector<QString> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        QString title = QStringLiteral("hello %1").arg(i + dataCount);
        list.push_back(title);
    }
    listModal->addChatItems(list);
}
```

It feels like no other method is called, the output in data () seems to get the data of line 100 first, and then get the rest of the data.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: your beginInsertRows() is wrong in addChatItem() (but correct in addChatItems()).
btw: why all this useless conversions to/from std::string and all the 'this->' stuff? It's not java...

Comment: ```addChatItem()``` never used, I only used addChatItems for bulk addition.

Comment: Also, I use "std::string" to create a lot of different list data. I added "this->" just to make it look better.

Comment: Your columnCount() function is also wrong. std::string() and this-> is still not needed - make it just harder to read and see the real problem. Please update your post and provide a minimal, compilable exaxmple.

Comment: yep， like that？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though more like a real minimal, compilable example - it's working fine for me:

```
class ChatListItemModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const override { return m_chatItem.count(); }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override {
        if (index.isValid() && index.row() < m_chatItem.size() && index.row() >= 0 && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            return m_chatItem.at(index.row());
        return QVariant();
    }
    void addChatItems(const QVector<QString> &items)
    {
        if (items.isEmpty())
            return;
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),
                        m_chatItem.size(),
                        m_chatItem.size() + items.size() - 1
                        );
        m_chatItem.append(items);
        endInsertRows();
    }
    void addTwoMoreItems()
    {
        QVector<QString> items;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i)
            items.push_back(QStringLiteral("New item %1").arg(i));
        addChatItems(items);
    }
private:
    QVector<QString> m_chatItem;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ChatListItemModel model;
    QVector<QString> items;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 99; ++i)
        items.push_back(QStringLiteral("Item %1").arg(i));
    model.addChatItems(items);
    QListView view;
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.show();
    view.scrollToBottom();

    QTimer::singleShot(5000, &model, &ChatListItemModel::addTwoMoreItems);    
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I have tried my best to be consistent with your example.
Except that I used a custom Delegate, we should know as much as possible. I am going to modify the content. Please help me and take a look.
An example is that it can be rendered, for example, to render 1000 data, and then I scroll the current list to the 300th item. At this time, after I add data to the list, the scroll position of the list will scroll to the 100th item.

Comment: I can run through your example, but I am still thinking about what is wrong

Comment: So modify your example until the error no longer occours - I can't compile your stuff since it is neither minimal nor compilable so you're on your own.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Is my problem. Remember the code I first posted？There ```setLayoutMode(QListView::LayoutMode::Batched);```, When redrawing, it will choose a batch layout, the default is 100 items

Comment: I will be your eternal follower~ Can I still ask you if I encounter an unsolvable problem?

Comment: I encountered another unexpected problem, can you take a look at it  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208412/how-to-remove-the-blank-area-of-qtabwidget) 