# How to remove the blank area of QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt

TabBar is hidden in the custom TabWidget, and then there are some margins that I cannot hide

[image: Click to view pictures]

Try `setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` Does not work

example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTabBar>
#include <QTabWidget>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.resize(900, 900);

    QWidget *contentWidget = new QWidget(&mainWindow);
    QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget(contentWidget);

    QWidget *myWidget = new QWidget;

    QPalette palette = myWidget->palette();
    myWidget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Window, QColor(255, 0, 255));
    myWidget->setPalette(palette);
    tabWidget->addTab(myWidget, "test");
    tabWidget->setTabPosition(QTabWidget::West);
    tabWidget->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    tabWidget->tabBar()->setExpanding(false);
    tabWidget->tabBar()->hide();

    QHBoxLayout layout;
    layout.setMargin(0);
    layout.setSpacing(0);
    layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout.addWidget(tabWidget, 1);

    contentWidget->setLayout(&layout);
    contentWidget->show();

    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(contentWidget);
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I searched for answers in many places, but I did not find the desired result.

Comment: Please edit your code to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The question is totally unclear to me. Do you want to remove the margin? Add a tab with code? Let the user add a tab dynamically? What do you mean with switch?

Comment: Sorry, this is a very simple example of QTabWidget, but I am not in front of the computer, my English level is not very good, sorry again, what I want to say is, I want to hide the blank area indicated by the picture

Comment: The blank area may be caused by a layout.

Comment: I added a simple example, it can reproduce the problem on the mac system, and I did not add extra layout attributes

Comment: [This problem has been solved.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/113695/qtabwidget-how-to-remove-the-blank-area-of-qtabwidget)
Thanks everyone.